# Trouble on constant order statements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, constants

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.1 and I would like to understand how to solve the following issue in the right way when I state constants.

I have 2 classes:

```
class Class1 < ActiveRecord::Base
  CONSTANT_CLASS_1_A = Class2::CONSTANT_CLASS_2_A # => 222
  CONSTANT_CLASS_1_B = 111
end

class Class2 < ActiveRecord::Base
  CONSTANT_CLASS_2_A = 222
  CONSTANT_CLASS_2_B = Class1::CONSTANT_CLASS_1_B # => 111
end
```

When I try to "use"/"load" the `Class1` I get the following error:

```
NameError in ...
uninitialized constant Class1::CONSTANT_CLASS_2_B
```

However, if I state the below code (note the constant statement order) it will work:

```
class Class1 < ActiveRecord::Base
  CONSTANT_CLASS_1_B = 1
  CONSTANT_CLASS_1_A = CONSTANT_CLASS_2_A * CONSTANT_CLASS_3_B # => 3
end
```

I know that I can state the `CONSTANT_CLASS_1_B` before the `CONSTANT_CLASS_1_B` (at least to "solve" the problem at this time), but **is it correct? That is, is there a way to solve my issue in a "right" and "*performant*" way** (for example, loading all `Class1` constants before to retrieve other constants)**? Is it advisable to use the above code?**

*Bonus*: There is a convention for this kind of issues? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to do this is probably have just one constant referencing the data you're looking for. Doubling up definitions leads to problems like this and additionally will make your code hard to read and understand.

If there isn't a really compelling reason to have the same constant in two places -- and there almost never is -- don't define CONSTANT_CLASS_2_B or CONSTANT_CLASS_1_A. If you want them, reference them from the other model like this:

```
Class2::CONSTANT_CLASS_2_A
Class1::CONSTANT_CLASS_1_B
```

Comment: "Doubling up definitions leads to problems like this and additionally will make your code hard to read and understand" - It is also true that it make the code more explicit (I think this is an advantage/benefit to understand the underlying class).

Comment: As long as the constant name is reasonably understandable, referencing it in another model is just as explicit -- saying User::EMAIL_REGEX makes it pretty obvious what you're looking for and where you're looking for it.

Comment: You could be right, but *I* think it is better understandable the "double" statement (that is, to be explicit) especially when you have to read and understand a class source code taken individually.